# 504 Gateway error on huge sql query in php

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I've a project in which I'm storing some data from xml file into my database, which the data is so huge that it takes some time, few data is inserted like 30thousands and then I get 504 gateway timeout.
I've tried increasing max_execution_time from php.ini but that didnt work. Im using cpanel

myscript

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file($url) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
        $totalproducts = $xml->shop->offers->offer->count();
        for($x=0 ; $x < $totalproducts; $x++){
            if(!empty($xml->shop->offers->offer[$x])){
                $name = $xml->shop->offers->offer[$x]->name;
                $price = $xml->shop->offers->offer[$x]->price;
                $description = $xml->shop->offers->offer[$x]->description;
                // $description = preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]#', "", $description);
                $description = str_replace('"', "", $description);
                $description = str_replace("'", "", $description);
                // $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($description);
                $imglink = $xml->shop->offers->offer[$x]->picture;
                $url = $xml->shop->offers->offer[$x]->url;
                $catname = 'shoes';
                $program = $_POST['programname'];
                $sql = "INSERT into products(categoryname,productname,productdiscription,price,url,program,image) VALUES('$catname','$name','$description','$price','$url','$program', '$imglink')";
                if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                    // echo "New record created successfully";
                } else {
                    // echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: And how to help out? Why do you run such a huge process over the webserver process, and not using CLI? Additionally, you should look up prepared statements (to avoid SQL injection) and the `INSERT` syntax to insert multiple rows in a single query

Comment: There are multiple issues with this snippet. It lacks input sanitization (prone to SQL injection attacks), is too chatty (should do bulk operations), has no retries or resume (upon failure starts from the first record each time), is part of a synchronous operation (should be offloaded to some other component), lacks error handling (what if your DB is unavailable?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem comes from "simplexml_load_file()" function. probably loading xml takes much time.
If you sure about the function, I add a few code line to prevent timeout, but not decreasing time:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['offset'])){$offset=$_GET['offset'];}
else {$offset=0;}

$xml=simplexml_load_file($url) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
        $totalproducts = $xml->shop->offers->offer->count();
        for($x=$offset ; ($x < $totalproducts && ($x < (($offset+1)*100)); $x++){
            if(!empty($xml->shop->offers->offer[$x])){
                $name = $xml->shop->offers->offer[$x]->name;
                $price = $xml->shop->offers->offer[$x]->price;
                $description = $xml->shop->offers->offer[$x]->description;
                // $description = preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]#', "", $description);
                $description = str_replace('"', "", $description);
                $description = str_replace("'", "", $description);
                // $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($description);
                $imglink = $xml->shop->offers->offer[$x]->picture;
                $url = $xml->shop->offers->offer[$x]->url;
                $catname = 'shoes';
                $program = $_POST['programname'];
                $sql = "INSERT into products(categoryname,productname,productdiscription,price,url,program,image) VALUES('$catname','$name','$description','$price','$url','$program', '$imglink')";
                if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                    // echo "New record created successfully";
                } else {
                    // echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                }
            }
        }
Header("Location: yourpage.php?offset=".($offset+100));
echo ($offset+100).' items inserted';
?>
```

This splits inserting to 100 items by 100 items. you can change 100 to more items at each time.